# Change the data types and load into different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a big delimited flat file which has 170 columns. I have loaded this flat file into SQL Server using import/export wizard.

When I load this flat file, all columns are stored as `varchar` data type. I need to convert many of these columns into different data types like `date`, `bigint`, `decimal`, `smallint` etc. and need to load these columns into different tables.

Do I need to use SSIS packages or can I do it in SQL Server?

Can anyone suggest a good procedure to do this?

I really appreciate your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in t-sql and as someone who does ETL via SSIS, t-sql, c# etc. I will say this task is strongly preferred in t-sql over SSIS!  in SSIS you would have to create a data transformation for all 170 columns and specify type on source as well as destination.....

Do you already know the datatypes you need for the columns?  If so and you have the table built it gets easier yet.  Just write a really really long insert statement with a select from your original table and in the select `CAST` or `CONVERT` from `varchar` to the desired datatype.  The conversion is the tricky part as the insert will fail if the conversion fails do to data in the columns.  You can use sys.columns and sys.types to do it dynamically so you don't have 170 different columns a few times.....

This should get you started if you don't want to write all of the data types etc.... Still needs work but a guide.

```
;WITH cteColumns AS (
    SELECT
       ColumnName = c.name
       ,DataType = CASE
          WHEN ty.name LIKE '%CHAR%' THEN ty.Name + '(' + CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
          WHEN ty.name IN ('DECIMAL','NUMERIC') THEN ty.name + '(' + CAST(c.precision AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
          ELSE ty.name
       END
    FROM
       sys.columns c
       INNER JOIN sys.types ty
       ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    WHERE
       c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName')
)

SELECT
    ColumnName + ' = CAST(source.' + ColumnName + ' AS ' + DataType + ')'
FROM
    cteColumns
```

Comment: Good answer. You could use TRY_CONVERT which will stop failures. The issue being you may lose some data if it were used (it will insert a null if it doesn't work)

Comment: Thank you very much Matt and Rich Benner. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @AnjanaH glad that Vigya's article worked for you, but your question was how to move a SQL table (already loaded data) to a different SQL table with other datatypes and for 170 columns.  Whether you use CAST or STR is not of consequence the query I provided will still save you from writing 170 columns multiple times as it will allow you to form the STR('asdfasdf' as or CAST('asdfasdf' as by using system views.

Comment: Can I create a stored procedure to do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to import regularly**

Write import script it will be a one time job to write and you can use it regularly and also automate the process.Different ways to write import script: Please follow the link

### [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/)

You have already imported the file using import/export wizard and the problem is with datatype conversion, here is what I do.
I crate a table with proper datatype and insert into the created table from imported table, User mostly face the problem of integer converted into float datatype,

### use [STR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)

```
 LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(column_In_float,15))) as column_In_INT
```

--
Other conversion like VARCHAR/CHAR/DATE/DDATETIME/NUMERIC etc should be pretty easy.

---